# What are health benefits of DGL Licorice

Tags: digestion, supplement

I've seen multiple product advertisements for DGL Licorice and was wondering if there is a scientific consensus on the health benefits of the product.

Comment: This is not a forum. "Has anyone tried this, and did it work?" is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: updated based on your comment.

Comment: Upvoted and close vote retracted. Much improved! Thanks!